# Difficulty using the arrange and filter functions within another function

Tags: r, dplyr

I've been using some of the functions available through dplyr to do the 3rd assignment, but am having trouble getting functions like arrange() and filter() to work within my functions. For example, if we take the example of the mtcars dataset, this works just fine:

```
s<-arrange(mtcars, carb)

print(s)
```

But, if I want to use arrange() within a function where I input whichever column I'd like to arrange by, arrange() doesn't seem to take the argument I use for the function. (see below)

```
Example <- function(column)

{

s<-arrange(mtcars, column)

print(s)

}

Example("carb")
```

This is the error message: 
 Error: incorrect size (1) at position 1, expecting : 32

Select() seems to work in this context, but I have the same difficulty with filter(). Any suggestions?

Thanks for considering,

Comment: add `!!sym(column)` to your arrange call

Comment: or possibly `{column}`. Is it a non-standard evaluation issue? https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html